# Javascript - When I click on an input, the associated object deletes itself

Tags: javascript, object, addeventlistener

I'm trying to create a GPA calculator (just to practice html, css, javascript) and am having an issue I can't seem to solve. Here's what's happening.

TL;DR: When I click on an input field, the corresponding object is erased.

For each course, there is a form with input fields for course name (text input), grade (select input), and credits earned (number input). When you want to add another course, you're adding another form. When a form is created, so is an object that's associated with it. I create this association by adding an id to the form with a unique number and also adding that id number to the object.

When I console.log the various steps of creating an object and setting its values and saving it to the local storage, everything works fine. However, when I was trying to create functionality to update the values of the objects, I started having troubles. I've pinpointed when they happen. Whenever I click on an input field, the object is erased. Specifically, only the object that's tied to that input field is erased. So if I create 5 forms and I click on the text input of the 3rd one, the 3rd object is erased. I can click on that same field multiple times and nothing else will happen. Then, if I click, say, the number input of the 5th form, then the 5th object is erased. I know it's not the delete function at work because that function would also remove the form from view.

If anyone could help me pinpoint what I can do to fix this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Javascript

```
// Theme
let lightMode = document.getElementById('light-mode');
let darkMode = document.getElementById('dark-mode');

lightMode.addEventListener('click', () => {themeTransition(); document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'light');});
darkMode.addEventListener('click', () => {themeTransition(); document.documentElement.setAttribute('data-theme', 'dark');});

function themeTransition()
{
    document.documentElement.classList.add('transition');
    window.setTimeout(() => document.documentElement.classList.remove('transition'), 1000);
}

//  GPA CALCULATION

// Object ID
var objId = 0;

// Grades class
class Grades
{
    constructor(id, course, grade, credits)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.course = course;
        this.grade = grade;
        this.credits = credits;
    }
}

// Storage class
class Store
{
    static getGrades()
    {
        let grades;
        
        if (localStorage.getItem('grades') == null)
        {
            grades = [];
        }
        else
        {
            grades = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('grades'));
            objId = localStorage.getItem('objId');
        }

        return grades;
    }

    static addGrade(grade, newObjId)
    {
        const grades = Store.getGrades();

        grades.push(grade);
        localStorage.setItem('grades', JSON.stringify(grades));
        localStorage.setItem('objId', JSON.stringify(newObjId));

        console.log(grades);
    }

    static updateGrade(id, course, grade, credits)
    {
        const grades = Store.getGrades();

        grades.forEach((oldGrade, index) =>
        {
            if (oldGrade.id == id)
            {
                oldGrade[index].course = course;
                oldGrade[index].grade = grade;
                oldGrade[index].credits = credits;
            }
        });

        localStorage.setItem('grades', JSON.stringify(grades));
    }

    static removeGrade(id)
    {
        const grades = Store.getGrades();

        grades.forEach((grade, index) =>
        {
            if (grade.id == id)
            {
                grades.splice(index, 1);
            }
        });
        localStorage.setItem('grades', JSON.stringify(grades));
    }
}

// UI class
class UI
{
    static displayGrades()
    {
        const grades = Store.getGrades();

        grades.forEach((grade) => UI.addCurrentGrade(grade));
    }

    static addCurrentGrade(grade)
    {
        const list = document.querySelector('.add-grades');
        const row = document.createElement('form');
        const addBefore = document.querySelector('.add');

        row.classList.add('add-item');
        row.setAttribute('id', `${grade.id}`)
        row.innerHTML =
        `
            <div class="input-node course">
                <label for="course">Course</label>
                <input type="text" id="course">
            </div>
            <div class="input-node grade">
                <label for="grade">Grade</label>
                <select id="grade">
                    <option value="none"></option>
                    <option value="A">A</option>
                    <option value="A-">A-</option>
                    <option value="B+">B+</option>
                    <option value="B">B</option>
                    <option value="B-">B-</option>
                    <option value="C+">C+</option>
                    <option value="C">C</option>
                    <option value="C-">C-</option>
                    <option value="D+">D+</option>
                    <option value="D">D</option>
                    <option value="D-">D-</option>
                    <option value="F">F</option>
                    <option value="W">W</option>
                    <option value="I">I</option>
                    <option value="P">P</option>
                    <option value="NP">NP</option>
                </select>
            </div>
            <div class="input-node credits">
                <label for="credits">Credits</label>
                <input type="number" id="credits">
            </div>
            <div class="input-node delete">
                <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
            </div>
        `;
        list.insertBefore(row, addBefore);
        document.querySelector('.delete').addEventListener('click', delGrade);
        document.querySelector('.add-grades').addEventListener('input', updateGrades);
    }

    static addNewGrade(e)
    {
        if (e.parentElement.classList.contains('add-grade'))
        {
            objId++;
            const currentId = objId;
            
            const list = document.querySelector('.add-grades');
            const row = document.createElement('form');
            const addBefore = document.querySelector('.add');

            row.classList.add('add-item');
            row.setAttribute('id', `${currentId}`)
            row.innerHTML =
            `
                <div class="input-node course">
                    <label for="course">Course</label>
                    <input type="text" id="course">
                </div>
                <div class="input-node grade">
                    <label for="grade">Grade</label>
                    <select id="grade">
                        <option value="none"></option>
                        <option value="A">A</option>
                        <option value="A-">A-</option>
                        <option value="B+">B+</option>
                        <option value="B">B</option>
                        <option value="B-">B-</option>
                        <option value="C+">C+</option>
                        <option value="C">C</option>
                        <option value="C-">C-</option>
                        <option value="D+">D+</option>
                        <option value="D">D</option>
                        <option value="D-">D-</option>
                        <option value="F">F</option>
                        <option value="W">W</option>
                        <option value="I">I</option>
                        <option value="P">P</option>
                        <option value="NP">NP</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
                <div class="input-node credits">
                    <label for="credits">Credits</label>
                    <input type="number" id="credits">
                </div>
                <div class="input-node delete">
                    <i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i>
                </div>
            `;
            list.insertBefore(row, addBefore);
            document.querySelector('.delete').addEventListener('click', delGrade);
            document.querySelector('.add-grades').addEventListener('input', updateGrades);

            const course = e.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#course').value;
            const grade = e.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#grade').value;
            const credits = e.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#course').value;

            const grades = new Grades(currentId, course, grade, credits);
            Store.addGrade(grades, currentId);
        }
    }
    
    static deleteGrade(del)
    {
        if (del.parentElement.classList.contains('delete'))
        {
            del.parentElement.parentElement.remove();
        }
    }
}

// EVENTS

// Display Existing Grades
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', UI.displayGrades);

// Add Grade
document.querySelector('.add-grade').addEventListener('click', (e) => 
{
    UI.addNewGrade(e.target);
});

// Update Grade
document.querySelector('.add-grades').addEventListener('input', updateGrades);

function updateGrades(e)
{
    const id = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('id');
    const course = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#course').value;
    const grade = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#grade').value;
    const credits = e.target.parentElement.parentElement.querySelector('#course').value;

    Store.updateGrade(id, course, grade, credits);
}

// Remove Grade
document.querySelector('.add-grades').addEventListener('click', delGrade);

function delGrade(e)
{
    UI.deleteGrade(e.target);
    Store.removeGrade(e.target.parentElement.parentElement.getAttribute('id'));
}

document.body.addEventListener('click', testFun);

function testFun()
{
    const grades = Store.getGrades();
    console.log(grades);
}
```

note: function testFun() is to log the objects in the Grades class whenever I click on anything

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" data-theme="light">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.13.1/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-xxzQGERXS00kBmZW/6qxqJPyxW3UR0BPsL4c8ILaIWXva5kFi7TxkIIaMiKtqV1Q" crossorigin="anonymous">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <title>GPA Calculator</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="view-mode">
                <button id="light-mode">Light</button> | <button id="dark-mode">Dark</button>
            </div>
            <header class="header">
                <h1>GPA</h1>
                <h2>Calculator</h2>
            </header>
            <section class="add-grades">
                <div class="table-header">
                    <h1>Semester <span class="semester">–</span></h1>
                    <h2>Semester GPA: <span class="gpa-semester">–</span></h2>
                </div>
                <div class="add add-grade">
                    <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
                </div>
            </section>
            <div class="add add-semester">
                <i class="fas fa-plus-circle"></i>
            </div>
            <aside class="gpa-total">
                <h2>GPA</h2>
                <h1><span class="gpa-total">–</span></h1>
            </aside>
        </div>
        <script src="main.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

If you want the full effect, here's the CSS as well

```
/* Global */
html[data-theme="light"]
{
    --background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
    --panel: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    --panel-head: rgb(0, 80, 190);
    --text: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    --text-secondary: rgb(60, 60, 60);
    --text-panel: rgb(20, 20, 20);
    --text-panel-head: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    --add: rgb(58, 180, 34);
    --delete: rgb(255, 55, 55);
}
html[data-theme="dark"]
{
    --background: rgb(40, 40, 40);
    --panel: rgb(70, 70, 70);
    --panel-head: rgb(0, 106, 255);
    --text: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    --text-secondary: rgb(120, 120, 120);
    --text-panel: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    --text-panel-head: rgb(245, 245, 245);
    --add: rgb(58, 180, 34);
    --delete: rgb(255, 55, 55);
}
*
{
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
body
{
    background: var(--background);
    font-family: Cochin, Georgia, Times, 'Times New Roman', serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    color: var(--text);
}
.container
{
    width: 80%;
    margin: auto;
}
button
{
    background: none;
    border: none;
    outline: none;
}

/* Header */
#view-mode
{
    text-align: right;
    margin-top: 20px;
}
#view-mode button
{
    font-size: 16px;
    color: var(--text);
}
#view-mode button:hover
{
    color: var(--panel-head);
    text-decoration: underline;
    cursor: pointer;
}
.header
{
    margin: 20px 0 50px 0;
    text-align: center;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
.header h1
{
    font-size: 6em;
}
.header h2
{
    font-size: 1.77em;
    color: var(--text-secondary);
}

/* User Input */
.add-grades
{
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
    background: var(--panel);
    color: var(--text-panel);
    border-radius: 20px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.table-header
{
    padding: 10px 15px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: baseline;
    border-top-right-radius: 20px;
    border-top-left-radius: 20px;
    background: var(--panel-head);
    color: var(--text-panel-head);
}
.table-header h1
{
    font-size: 2em;
}
.table-header h2
{
    font-size: 1.2em;
}
.add-item
{
    padding: 10px;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.add-item .input-node
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    align-items: center;
}
.add-item .input-node *
{
    margin: 0 3px;
}
.input-node #course
{
    width: 75px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.input-node #grade
{
    font-size: 1em;
    outline: none;
}
.input-node #credits
{
    width: 40px;
    padding: 5px;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 5px;
    outline: none;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.delete i
{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    padding: 0;
    color: var(--text-panel);
}
.delete i:hover
{
    color: var(--delete);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.add-grades .add
{
    margin: 13px;
    margin-top: 10;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-end;
}
.add i
{
    font-size: 1.4em;
    color: var(--text-panel);
}
.add i:hover
{
    color: var(--panel-head);
    cursor: pointer;
}
.container > .add
{
    min-width: 400px;
    max-width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 20px;
}

/* GPA Calculation */
.gpa-total
{
    margin-top: 50px;
    text-align: center;
}
.gpa-total h2
{
    font-size: 3em;
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}
.gpa-total h1
{
    width: 250px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-top: 10px;
    padding: 60px 0;
    font-size: 6em;
    border-radius: 100%;
    background: var(--panel-head);
    color: var(--text-panel-head);
    box-shadow: 0 0 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
}

/* Transition */
html.transition,
html.transition body,
html.transition body:before,
html.transition body:after,
html.transition section,
html.transition section:before,
html.transition section:after
{
    transition: all 750ms !important;
    transition-delay: 0 !important;
}
```

Comment: You keep adding numerous click event listeners to `.add-grades`. Add a console log statement inside your various handler functions and you will see how often each of them gets called with a single click

Comment: @charlietfl I figured it out, thanks to your help. Whenever I would add a new form or display the forms from storage, I would add event listeners (so that the delete buttons would work). However, I also kept the ones in the events list there, so I think that was messing it up. Either way, I figured it out.